# AWS S3 images moved to glacier without even deleted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I have a Bucket on s3 where we store images for our sites. We have enabled versioning on this bucket and lifecycle policy as "move to glacier after 14 days of deletion".

But some of my images moved to glacier automatically without even deleted.
I have to restore my images everytime as it is quite frequent for my site.

for example:

http://cdn.storehippo.com/s/54be61bdb4c246161e003df7/ms.products/58f0837ddfa2c9603d601d92/images/58f0837ddfa2c9603d601d94/58f0837f2e7e58e9609642b5/58f0837f2e7e58e9609642b5-240x240.jpg

http://cdn.storehippo.com/s/54be61bdb4c246161e003df7/ms.products/58a15d969a9ad09239f7e5b3/images/58a15d969a9ad09239f7e5b5/58a15d9cab94096610c5bd44/58a15d9cab94096610c5bd44-240x240.jpg

Comment: It sounds like you have more than one lifecycle policy.  Verify the policies. Enable logging on your bucket to be *certain* they aren't being inadvertently deleted.